# How does the yahoo messenger work?

Tags: ajax, yahoo-messenger

Edited Question :

I decided to create an online chat for our site users and for get more details and experience , visit some chatrooms and compared them by yahoo online messenger.
All chatrooms worked by Ajax ( call repeatedly to server even when wasn't new messages or any changes to display ) and had 4 second timeout between every call.

But yahoo online messenger connect to server just when it is needed and work faster than.

- Please share your knowledge about it.
- Does it may to create one like that or use of thats power ( or any other same services ) for our site ( and was private ) ?

Thank you .

Comment: I think it is a proprietary protocol. Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Messenger_Protocol

Comment: There are some IM (Instant Messaging) Applications working with the messenger.

Comment: thanks all.and special thanks to pss.

Comment: my wrong was because of i thought that it [just] works by Ajax!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Messenger_Protocol) says that

> YMSG is a proprietary protocol, a closed standard aligned only with
>   the Yahoo! messaging service. Rival messaging services have their own
>   protocols, some based on open standards, others proprietary, each
>   effectively fulfilling the same role with different mechanics.

Also If you are interested in building some application then visit this [official page](http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/).
There are also some projects already done using different programming languages like C++, Java. For eg: [libyahoo2](http://libyahoo2.sourceforge.net/),  [OpenYMSG](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openymsg/)

Here is an [interesting study](http://www.ldelgado.es/otros/crypt4you/study_im_protocols_and_chat.pdf) about different instant messaging protocols.

Comment: thank you pss for these details .